# how to change placeholder color in mat-select in angular 8

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I am trying to change my placeholder color and background color of my select box after its `mat-focussed`, but the color or background is not changing. It is fixed with same primary blue color .

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
         <mat-select  placeholder="Select Function">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let option of functionOptions" [value]="option.name">
                    {{option.name}}
           </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
```

scss

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
   color: #4dff91!important;
   background-color : grey;
}
```

I tried even changing place holder to mat-label and given css for mat-label ,still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the css without ::ng-deep

```css
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
   color: #4dff91 !important;
   background-color : grey;
}
```